# How can I ignore lines while reading a text file in R?

Tags: r

I have a text file with tens of thousands of rows, with time stamps such as `2010  5  3  0  0` interspersed in between. They are not consistent, but the 2 rows are.

How can I import the 2 columns (trial and the number), while ignoring the rows where I have these timestamps?

```
a <- read.table('test.txt')
```

Currently, I get this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 5 did not have 2 elements
```

Data

```
 Trial  0.214526266019124
 Trial  0.213914388985549
 Trial  0.213886659329060
 Trial  0.213886587273578
2010  5  3  0  0
 Trial  0.213886587273578
 Trial  0.213256610071994
 Trial  0.213232963405967
 Trial  0.213232928149832
2011  2  3  0  0
 Trial  0.213886587273578
 Trial  0.213256610071994
 Trial  0.213232963405967
 Trial  0.213232928149832
 Trial  0.213886587273578
 Trial  0.213256610071994
 Trial  0.213232963405967
2011  2  6  0  0
```

Comment: I would use `readLines()` to read it in and filter them out afterwards using some regex command. You can export the result character vector using `sink()` and `cat()` to write it back into a text file. The smarter way of doing this is using the command line to delete certain lines within text files. This should be a `UNIX` related question to help filter your data.

Comment: I am thinking a) readlines b) ignore lines that don't have `trial`...Not sure if it will work. Trying..

Comment: See this post, this answers your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25682303/5874001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read.table` (or other function) in combination with `grep`:

```
read.table(text=grep("Trial", readLines(path_to_your_file), value=TRUE))
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This is the same answer (basically) as in the link I posted. You could argue the OP has posted a duplicate question.

Comment: I was preparing the answer and haven't seen your comment and we have something much simpler here, don't we?

Comment: Yeah, it is I guess. It's the same idea really, a good one! If the OP doesn't get marked as a duplicate, yours should be the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! Succinct. I tried is over a subset of the data, and it works, but it's really slow for thousands of lines...

Comment: There's not really a work around using readLines here I think. If you're concerned about speed, JeanVuda's suggestion might be quicker, but processing your data beforehand using what I recommend in the comments in the OP is what one should normally do.

Comment: You might consider using `fread` from the `data.table` package for speed.  It will actually accept a shell command, such as `"grep Trial test.txt"`, for input.

Answer (score 2):

if you have perl, you can do the data cleaning with it and capture the output without leaving R using `pipe`. Having to escape regex and quotes in the perl "one-liner" makes it a little weird and probably better as it's own script.

The pipe to perl here is maybe more complicated than you need. `perl -lne 'print $1 if m/Trial  (.*)/'` would probably suffice. Below captures the time stamp and appends it to all the lines until timestamp is found. `\W+` matches one or more white space characters, but needs the extra escape to be escaped from R's parser and passed to perl: `\\W+`. `\"` is used to keep R from thinking the string we are giving to it has ended, while still allowing string delimiters in perl (could use `qq(..)` instead of `"..."` in perl).

```
a <- read.table(
   pipe("perl -lne  '
        BEGIN{$ts=\"0 0 0 0 0\"} 
        chomp; 
        if(/Trial\\W+(.*)/){ 
           print \"$1 $ts\" 
       } else {
         $ts=$_
      }' test.txt"))
```

for the example data, the output would be

```
         V1   V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 0.2145263    0  0  0  0  0
2 0.2139144    0  0  0  0  0
3 0.2138867    0  0  0  0  0
4 0.2138866    0  0  0  0  0
5 0.2138866 2010  5  3  0  0
6 0.2132566 2010  5  3  0  0
7 0.2132330 2010  5  3  0  0
8 0.2132329 2010  5  3  0  0
```

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt<-readLines("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\new2.txt")
table<-strsplit(txt[grepl("T",substr(txt,1,1))],split = "\\s\\s")
table<-do.call("rbind", table)
```